# how to add parameter in parameter decorator?

Tags: typescript

I have a class like this:

```
export class fooController{

constructor( @inject(true) private fooService: fooService) {

   }
}
```

I want to implement the parameter decorator with passing an argument on it.

I had tried with the below approach, but it doesn't work, by giving error as "Supplied parameter doesn't match any signature of call target"

```
  public static inject(isFoo: boolean = false) {
    return (target: any, key: String, index: number) => {

     }
  }
```

Please help me with the issue

Comment: You should at least add the error (message). Anyhow, you can read more about the parameter decorator here: http://blog.wolksoftware.com/decorators-metadata-reflection-in-typescript-from-novice-to-expert-part-3

Comment: @SebastianSebald thanx for the reply, i had edited the error and i had read the above link before also , but they haven't wrote anything about passing argument to parameter decorator ,any idea is this feature even supported by typescript

Comment: Is `inject(true)` your actual code? Because every decorator has to be prefixed with an `@`. Maybe you can create a jsbin or something we can play with?